# Visual Studio 2017 debug MVC 403.14

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

I have a new laptop, so I clone the MVC project which I'm working, but I can not debug it when I click f5 debug it in IIS Express, the error message is `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.`
If I publish the project and create an application in local iis use it, it works.
I create a new MVC project, it can be debugged correctly.

vs2017
IIS Express 10.0
I create a new index.html file in the base folder, it will show correct so, i think the route is not working.
And I'm sure i don't need to set the enviroment of the new laptop.

Comment: make sure your web config can be accessed by your application

Comment: it is possible that program has no permission to read the web config

Comment: "but I can not debug it when I click f5 debug it in IIS Express". What was the URL showed in the web browser? It is possible to have a wrong URL in your project settings and prevent yourself from debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue with permission, probably is caused by changing environment and some assembly or some sort of file are lost and VS can find them, or if it can them are not compatible.

So try to create new project, copy and paste your code from the old project to the new.

Hope this help

Leo.